# Placing XML buttons on top of java buttons?

Tags: java, android, xml

Is there an XML code that will allow me to always have my XML buttons on top of the buttons I've created with java? Because right now it will only display my XML button when my java buttons are disabled.

XML Button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_student_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="blah.Blah">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        app:backgroundTint="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: view.bringToFront()

Comment: @EliasFazel I'm trying to bring the XML to the front, is there an XML code? I don't see a bringToBack() function to use to put my java buttons in the back.

Comment: in class after findViewById()

Answer (score 0):

```
android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
```

this is the ID of FloatingActionButton so declare it in this way

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
fab.bringToFront();
```

Comment: If I do this then it still shows only the button, is there a way to make them both visible? This just completely overrides the buttons I've created with java, and only shows the XML button on the screen.

Comment: change position of view in xml

Comment: It's in the bottom right corner and the java buttons don't go that far down so there isn't anyway they would overlap.